# Is rheostat the same thing as variable resistor?

Tags: terminology

In class notes, it is written that variable resistor is the same thing as a [rheostat](http://www.resistorguide.com/rheostat/). I googled it to find that some people on different question/answer forums have different "perspectives" about this. Some say that they are the same thing and some others say that they are not quite the same but they have the same effect which is varying the intensity of the current in a circuit.

I am kind of confused there and would appreciate your input on this.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, a rheostat is a variable resistor capable of handling higher power (0.5 to perhaps 10 watts) and a variable resistor (also called a potentiometer) is good for handling 1/4 to 1/2 watt. Otherwise, they are the same thing.